# Pseudo element using ::before overflow's parent element height

Tags: css, pseudo-element

Plunker code is [here](https://plnkr.co/edit/0DCFlnSxx2AkpBPnSWU3?p=preview).

I try to create a speech bubble whose top and bottom corners are same as the parent element's corners.

Pseudo element props are,

```
.callout::before {
      box-sizing: border-box;
      height: 100%;
      content: "";
      position: absolute;
      right: -0.2em;
      padding: 1em;
      background: inherit;
      border: inherit;
      border-right: 0;
      border-bottom: 0;
      transform: rotate(45deg);
      z-index: -1;
    }
```

I see problems as,

1) pseudo element is not cropped to parent element's height

2) pseudo element is not originating exactly from the top,right corner of the parent element

It looks like,

[image: img]

How can one fix it?

Comment: HOW do u want it to look

Comment: It will be difficult to get a proper looking diamond using relative values such as `height: 100%;` To do this convincingly, you need to use either a border triangle, or use set values for the height of the div, then set values for the height and width of the diamond.

Comment: Do you meant like this? [fiddle](http://codepen.io/anon/pen/PGoOgo)

Comment: ,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let us assume the parent element has height `x`. Since, you are using `::before` element to show the arrow by rotating it to `45deg`, the diagonal of the arrow should be equal to the height of the parent element. The formula of Diagonal is `side * sqrt(2)`. So,

```
    x = side * sqrt(2)

=>  side = x / sqrt(2)
```

Assuming, `x = 50`, then `side` will be `35.35534`. So, apply the same in your fiddle:

```
div {
    width: 100px;
    height: 50px;
    background: tomato;
    position: relative;
}

div::before {
    content: "";
    display: block;
    width: 35.35534px;
    height: 35.35534px;
    background: blue;
    position: absolute;
    transform: rotate(45deg);
    transform-origin: 0 0;
    left: 100%;
}
```

Better would be to go with a css preprocessor like SASS. Here is the code where I used sass to get the result.

**[Working Fiddle](http://codepen.io/anon/pen/PGoOgo)**